auditd logs- /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 flooding logs
I am running auditd on a Debian 11 server with a very generic set of audit rules. The audit log is filled with entries like below. I'm not sure what they are - can anyone help identify these? I'm assuming it has something to do with root executing something since the ouid and ogit are 0. Is this correct?
type=Path msg=audit(1712839234.13338212): item=2 name="/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" inode=1573503 dev=fe:05 mode=0100755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fe=0 fver=0 frootid=0


add your /etc/auditd/audit.rules file.  Kinda need that detail to figure what is causing that in the log and why.  My guess would be adding to the rule to exempt below a uid value or do a uid !=0 type of thing for the audit rule that is causing it.

Floria Roths’s:
https://github.com/Neo23x0/auditd

I looked at your link to Floria Roths's audit.rules file.  I would not call that a generic set of rules, it is pretty lengthy and encompassing.
But, you listed just one entry for msg=audit(1712839234.13338212). Is there more entries next to that one sharing the same 1712839234.13338212 timestamp ?
refer to this to begin to decipher the audit log syntax : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/auditing-the-system_security-hardening
type=PATH and name="/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2" basically says that ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 had been called by object owner uid 0 (root).  that's all i can decipher so far...
What is /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 and why can it be used to execute file?
on REHL 8.9 ls-l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 links to  ld-2.28.so and a yum whatprovides shows it comes from  glibc-2.28-225.el8_8.6.x86_64.  So all that can be said thus far is you have a lot of calling of the dynamic linker by root.  Which rule in that rules file is causing that I do not know, my first suggestion would be to

remove all rules, see if the log entry disappears,
then add chunks of rules back in until you narrow down which rule causes the log flood; i suggest doing all the -w rules first, then all the -a rules,
i did not have time to test your rules file.


remove the -e from the rules file so you don't have to reboot every time you make a change

i observe the ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 flood is surrounded by nvidia and modprobe on RHEL-8.9 with nvidia installed; my audit log floods.  On a separate system without nvidia installed running the same rules file I do not get that flood of entries.  I think it is around your rules having the perm_mod key, where -F auid=-1.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls

https://github.com/ComplianceAsCode/content/issues/1999

auid != -1 is likely wrong, you probably want some other check there. The -e nuked me and I can't reboot; to be continued when i have time

Good advice from everyone.  I found the offending line:
-a always,exit -F arch=b64 -F euid=0 auid>=1000 -F auid!=4294967295 -S execve -k rootcmd
Problem is I need to collect all of the commands the root user types
